# print out nsg with security rules using azure python network management module

Tags: python, azure, networking

I want to be able to use azure python network management module to print out exisiting NSG with security rules.

when I print out the result, I see
{
'additional_properties': {},
'id': '/subscriptions/1111-22222-33334--44444/resourceGroups/RG-US-e-Network/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/testnsg',
'name': 'NSG-E-E-BE',
'type': 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups',
'location': 'eastus',
'tags': {},
'etag': 'W/"a3d08ba5-3620-4ce3-88b5-48f859c5dbf5"',
'security_rules': [ < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616c88 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616cc0 > ],
'default_security_rules': [ < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616cf8 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616d30 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616da0 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616dd8 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616e10 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616e48 > ],
'network_interfaces': None,
'subnets': None,
'flow_logs': None,
'resource_guid': '8a360147-xxxx-46b8-b8be-xxxxxx',
'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded'
}

The security rule section doesn't list out rules but this:

'security_rules': [ < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616c88 > , < azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.SecurityRule object at 0x7f023e616cc0 > ],

maybe my print function is incorrect. what did I do wrong here? below is my simple code:

```
credential = AzureCliCredential()
#credential = DefaultAzureCredential
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "RG-EUS-ECS-Network"
nsg_name = "testnsg"

nsg_params = NetworkSecurityGroup(id= "testnsg", location="westus", tags={ "name" : "testnsg" })

nsglist = network_client.network_security_groups.list(resource_group_name)

pageobject=nsglist.by_page(continuation_token=None)

for page in pageobject:
    for i in page:
        print (i)
```

Answer (score 1):

The script you are using is printing the Network Security Groups Located in a resource group. To print the Network security rules for a NSG you have to use the below code:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "Your subid"
#credential = DefaultAzureCredential
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_group_name = "resourcegroupname"
nsg_name = "nsgname"
nsgruleslist = network_client.security_rules.list(resource_group_name,nsg_name)
pageobject1=nsgruleslist.by_page(continuation_token=None)
for page in pageobject1:
    for j in page:
        print(j)
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

The above displays all the security rules set on an NSG as shown in the image.